Overflow not working when height is not set in fixed positioned div
I have the following code where I'm trying to build a modal that doesn't have a height set, but do have a max-height so it adjusts to its content but doesn't grow bigger than certain limit. The problem is that I have to set the height property of the b element for the overflow inside the d and g elements to work, but with this it doesn't adjust to its content.


html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

.a {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #0001;
}

.b {
    padding: 1.4em;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px #0002;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: min(90%, 1200px);
    max-height: min(90%, 1000px);
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

.c {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    gap: 1em;
}

.d {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}

.e {
    flex-grow: 3;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0.5em;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.g {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <div contenteditable class="d">sidebar</div>
      <div class="e">
        <div class="f">
          top bar
        </div>
        <div contenteditable class="g"></div>
        <div class="h">
          pagination
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



You can test this code by editing the d and g elements (they are contenteditable) until they are bigger than the max-height of b and removing the height property of b.
Do you know what can be done for this to work without setting the height?

It does work if you remove height of b and just let max-height 

I edited my question, I need the overflow inside the d and g elements, not in the whole modal
